# Using generating functions to evaluate a sum

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, generating-functions

I have to use generating functions to evaluate the following sum :

$$\sum_{k=0}^n (k-1)k(k+1)$$

I think that first we have to find the generating function *C(x)* = $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n-1)n(n+1)x^n$.

I also computed the sum on WolframAlpha and know that the final result is $$\sum_{k=0}^n (k-1)k(k+1) = \frac{(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)}{4}$$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Here is one way to do it: consider $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n x^{k+1}$ (which you can evaluate in closed form) and note that $f'''(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n (k-1)k(k+1) x^{k-2} $

Comment: How did you know you had to use that function ?

Comment: I know that the derivative of $x^k$ is $kx^{k-1}$ so a term $(k-1)k(k+1)$ can be obtained as a third derivative of $x^{k+1}$. If we for example wanted to evaluate $\sum k^2$ instead then I would use that $x (x^k)' = k x^k$ so I would consider $f(x) = \sum x^k$ and compute $x[x f'(x)]'$ which has the general term $k^2 x^k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Winther already noted, let us define

$$f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} x^{k+1} = \dfrac{x(x^{n+1} - 1)}{x-1}$$

Then

$$f'''(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} (k+1)k(k-1)x^{k-2}$$

You shall compute the third derivative of $f(x) = \dfrac{x(x^{n+1} - 1)}{x-1}$ and the answer would be $f'''(1)$.

Comment: So the answer is the third derivative of f at 1 ? If I compute it I will get the answer I need to get (posted above ?)

Comment: @TedMosby Yes, you should get the same expression.

Comment: When I try to compute it online it won't give me any result, it seems very complicated to compute by hand but I'll try ! Thank you !

Comment: @TedMosby This may help you to check your steps while calculating the derivative: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x(x%5E(n%2B1)+-+1)%2F(x-1))'''

Comment: @TedMosby And the final answer is http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x(x%5E(n%2B1)+-+1)%2F(x-1))'''+for+x%3D1

Answer (score 1):

A small addendum: it is enough to exploit the [hockey stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity).
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(k-1)k(k+1) &=& 6\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{k+1}{3}\\&=& 6\binom{n+2}{4}\\&=&6\frac{(n+2)(n+1)n(n-1)}{4!}\\&=&\frac{(n+2)(n+1)n(n-1)}{4}.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{k - 1}k\pars{k + 1} & =
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{k + 1}^{\,\underline{3}} =
\left.{\pars{k + 1}^{\,\underline{4}} \over 4}\,\right\vert_{\ 0}^{\ n + 1} =
{\pars{n + 2}^{\,\underline{\,4}}\ -\ 1^{\,\underline{\,4}}\over 4}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{\ds{{\pars{n + 2}\pars{n + 1}n\pars{n - 1} \over 4}}}
\end{align}